# Git tried undoing all changes but ended up merging on the pull

Tags: git

I had un-commited changes I wanted to completely undo and have my workspace identical to the remote master. However, whilst pulling the latest code from master Git performed a merge and I don't understand why/what I did wrong.

I ran the following commands:

```
git status
```

This showed unstaged changes and new files.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

followed by an internal script to pull, which does:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```

but a merge occurred during the pull.

What did I do wrong/should I do different next time?

Comment: Can we see the relevant bits of `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all` please?

Comment: And when you say "identical to master" do you mean your local master or remote master?

Comment: @Schwern I mean remote. I just wanted to "start afresh"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had un-commited changes I wanted to completely undo and have my workspace identical to master.

To get rid of uncommitted changes:

`git reset --hard HEAD`. I have this aliased as `git clear`.

To have your workspace identical to local master:

`git checkout master`

To have your local master identical to remote master:

```
# Update origin
git fetch origin

git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

---

`git reset --hard HEAD~1` was a mistake. It undoes the latest commit. I have it aliased as `git undo`.

You can recover from this by checking `git reflog`, a record of how HEAD has changed, and looking for something like this:

```
b84779fe (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{5}: reset: moving to HEAD^
08d4b01b HEAD@{6}: commit: that commit you undid
```

The first line shows the undo. The second shows the commit it undid. So `git reset --hard 08d4b01b`.

---

> but a merge occurred during the pull.

This indicates your local master and remote master diverged. Usually because you made commits to your local master and somebody else pushed commits to the remote master. `git pull` is a `git fetch` to update your remote tracking branches (ie. origin/master) and a `git merge` to merge in the changes from the remote branch.

Here's what those two steps look like.

```
# Your local repository is out of date with origin.

origin
A - B - C - D - E [master]

local
A - B - C [origin/master]
         \
          F - G [master]

# Bring it up to date
$ git fetch origin

local
A - B - C - D - E [origin/master]
         \ 
          F - G [master]

# Merge in the new changes from origin/master to master.
$ git merge origin/master master

local
A - B - C - D - E [origin/master]
         \       \
          F - G - M [master]
```

This is one of the reasons I encourage leaving master alone.  All development should happen in [feature branches](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow) which are then reviewed, tested, and merged into master.